# How to Add scroll bar to html autocomplete datalist element?

Tags: php

Here is my PHP Code, I am trying to add a scroll bar to my autocomplete  search, I have retrieved data from database and wanted to add a scroll bar.:

```
<?php 
include('connection.php');
$result1 =  mysql_query("select * from legal_pashto");
$result2 =  mysql_query("select * from legal_dari");
$result3 =  mysql_query("select * from pashto_pashto");
$result4 =  mysql_query("select * from dari_pashto");
?>
<datalist id="words">
<?php   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)){?>
<option value="<?php print $row['english_word']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row['pashto_word']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row['pashto_word1']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row['pashto_word2']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row['pashto_word3']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row['pashto_word4']; ?>
<?php  }?>
<?php   while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)){?>
<option value="<?php print $row2['english_word']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row2['dari_word']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row2['dari_word1']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row2['dari_word2']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row2['dari_word3']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row2['dari_word4']; ?>
<?php  }?>
<?php   while($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)){?>
<option value="<?php print $row3['pashto_word']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row3['pashto_meaning']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row3['pashto_meaning1']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row3['pashto_meaning2']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row3['pashto_meaning3']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row3['pashto_meaning4']; ?>
<?php  }?>
<?php   while($row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result4)){?>
<option value="<?php print $row4['dariword']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row4['darimeaning']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row4['darimeaning1']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row4['darimeaning2']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row4['darimeaning3']; ?>
<option value="<?php print $row4['darimeaning4']; ?>
<?php  }?>
</datalist>
```

Comment: You forgot to paste your PHP code

Answer (score -1):

I am not very good when it comes to html but in my opinion adding your PHP code may help other help you. Just saying.

Comment: Entirely superfluous answer. Should be a comment.